# How to add and remove postfix for all files in folder using BATCH File

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, batch-rename

I'm trying to add and remove postfix from specific file types in all folders and subfolder.
I know the code for adding prefix but I don't know the code for postfix

Here is my code for prefix

**Adding PreFix:**

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\Temp\Test\"
for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir /s /b *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.wmv *.mpeg *.flv *.dat *.mov *.asf *.3gp *.srt') do (
   rename "%%j" "[my.prefix]-%%~nxj"
)
popd
```

**Removing PreFix:**

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\Temp\Test\"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.wmv *.mpeg *.flv *.dat *.mov *.asf *.3gp *.srt') do (
    set "fname=%%~nxa"
    set "fpath=%%~dpa"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "nname=!fname:~15!"
    ren "!fpath!!fname!" "!nname!"
    endlocal
)
popd
```

**How to do this for postfix?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add suffix**

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\Temp\Test\"
for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir /s /b *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.wmv *.mpeg *.flv *.dat *.mov *.asf *.3gp *.srt') do (
   rename "%%j" "%%~nj-[my.suffix]%%~xj"
)
popd
```

**Remove suffix**

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\Temp\Test\"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.wmv *.mpeg *.flv *.dat *.mov *.asf *.3gp *.srt') do (
    set "fname=%%~nxa"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "nname=!fname:-[my.suffix]=!"
    ren "%%a" "!nname!"
    endlocal
)
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set fileName=thisIsATest_0001
set fileExtension=.avi

echo %fileName:~0,-5%%fileExtension%
```

Negative values in second part of substring indicate distance from end of string